# Can I change the frame of UILabel runtime in IOS simulator by stretching the corner of UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, ios-simulator

I want to provide user to change the frame of label in simulator and adjust label frame as per text requirement .

Below is the image and can i make same view in IOS simulator to allow user change frame of label?

for label only and i want to show editable frame

[image]

If any one have idea how to do this thing or is it possible to do this type of functionality in IOS? 
let me know.!

Thanks

Comment: check this: https://github.com/kcandr/IQLabelView that third-party make easy code for your.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nitin Gohel  for awesome answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are one very nice class for make this task possible much easy. [IQLabelView is a Github project](https://github.com/kcandr/IQLabelView) that you need to use

**Import IQLabelView and add Label like following**

```
    IQLabelView *labelView = [[IQLabelView alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    labelView.delegate = self;
    [labelView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    [labelView setShowContentShadow:NO];
    [labelView setTextField:aLabel];
    [labelView setFontName:@"Baskerville-BoldItalic"];
    [labelView setFontSize:21.0];
    [labelView sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:labelView];
```

Comment: How can i limit the stretching of UILabel within uiview and text length?        i want that user can only stretch label within uiview.

Comment: For the using third party code we need to check the logic in deep so you have to debug code and learn for this limit :D

Comment: I am using IQLabelView in My project. IQLabelView uses a UITextField for text string. I have to use a line break into the string but could not achieve it because IQLabelView uses a textField instead a UITextView. Could you please suggest me another library similar this kind of functionality? I also tested JLStickerView, but installing via cocoapod, it shows several errors.

Answer (score 0):

To change size of UILabel according to text length you can use this code

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   


CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Hope this would help , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel according to text length .. Try only two line . It will auto adjust your max width and auto change height according to text .

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[yourLabel sizeToFit];
```